# display 125 words from the description field of the database mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hello fellow Overflows,

So im in the middle of creating a toplist script, ready to launch to the public, 
I'm stuck on one perticualr subject.

Displaying X amount of content from A database field.

```
<?php echo $server_data['description']; ?>
```

As you can see in this image below, That wouldn't be a good idea to display the full amount.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jA1z.png

What do i need? 
Instead of it displaying all of the database field, i just want it to display 150 characters of the field.

Comment: Do you mean a 'column' in a 'table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = substr($server_data['description'], 0, 150);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is best to limit characters while you are selecting from database because it will improve performance a bit. You can limit characters  on select with  mysql `LEFT()` function.
 Here is how to do it:

`SELECT LEFT(description, 150), another_col FROM ......`

Answer (score 0):

`substr()` will only return a certain amount of **characters**. If you want a certain amount of **words** then you could use the following:

```
<?php
function excerpt($content = '',$number_words = 125){
    $content = strip_tags($content);

    $contentWords = substr_count($content," ") + 1;

    $words = explode(" ",$content,($number_words+1));

    $excerpt = join(" ",$words);

    return $excerpt;

}


echo excerpt($server_data['description'], 125);
```